# Table auto-adjustable, is it possible?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

So, I have a sheet with a table which is dynamic.
Everytime I change an ID, the table auto reloads (based in a data base).

Sometimes, when reloaded, I got 5 rows, in other cases, 10. I have no max number of rows that can be returned, but it will be less than 100, I guess.

So, I'd like a way to "format" the table (about the design), waiting it to add one more row asked "TOTAL" after the last row returned when changed the ID (said above).

If it returns 10 rows, it should enclose every edge of the table, and add 11rd row with the "TOTAL".

Is it possible without VBA?

**EDIT**

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liWbi.png)

I just wanted the values in A18 and B18 automatically go to the A6 and B6.
And if the table updates, the TOTAL do the same as well.

Comment: Why is your question tagged as vba if you want to achieve it without vba?

Comment: If it cannot be done without, I'll try with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, why not just use inbuilt total row in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)*?*

---

1. Click anywhere inside your table

   - Note, if you only have data, simply select your datarange and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to create a table
2. Select the `Design` tab
3. Check the "`Total Row`" checkbox

   [image]

> Now the last row of your table will always show the "total row" on the
>   last row, regardless of how many datarows your table actually has.
>
> [image]

Comment: As I said, the table is "dynamic".
I'm not sure about the quantity of rows, and wanted the total were the right after (the last) row.

Comment: I added an image in the first post, hope it clears the intention.

Comment: @thiagohfl my answer has dynamic table in mind. If the table had 3 data rows, then the total would be on 4th row